# MapView extends when BottomNavigationView is gone

Tags: java, android

So every time is set my BottomNavigationView on gone the MapView gets bigger in size and when I set it back to visible it shrinks back to its original size. Is there a way to make the MapView have the size of the full screen even when the BottomNavigationView is visible ? Here is a GIF

[image]

Comment: Please post your layout XML as well

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to make the `MapView` have the size of the full screen even when the BottomNavigationView is visible ?

Yes there is.

Use something like `RelativeLayout` as the root layout and set the width and height of the `MapView` to `match_parent`.

Also add the `BottomNavigationView` as the child of root layout with attribute `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`.

Most importantly, do not use `LinearLayout` as parent and do not place the `MapView` and `BottomNavigationView` relative to each other.